# Laravel + VUEJS web VS API, store data after login

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, session, jwt

I have an application laravel + vuejs and they are seperated (front end and back end) and also vuejs is built to web/mobile.

Which is better to use web.php or api.php?

I have login in my application and also I need to store some data after the user login in auth or session.

Another issue:
When the user logged in, I need to store the account that the user choose after login (the user can be connected to multiple accounts) in session or auth, currently I'm using api.php not web.php, is there a way to store the data after login and have it all the time that the user is logged in?

Regards,
Bashar

Comment: IMHO, I think it is better to use stick to core PHP and not use frameworks.  When I see a programmer on this site having  a problem with Laravel, the Laravel code is no better than core PHP and  mySQL, it just different.  Did you choose on your own to use  Laravel or is it required by an employer or client?   Can you help me understand how Laravel  could help me?   Keep in mind I started making web apps with Netscape 1.1 in 1995.

Comment: web.php and api.php, i hope you are talking about the routers files, web and api both have different task to handle(calling api and calling views with data (via controller or direct)  and you can accomplish same task both ways. and m bit confused about the task you want to achive. like you want to save the data and you want to save the user who saved the data, you can do it via saving the userid with respected entry.